# Spring Boot Info end point

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

We have application.yml with the following information

```
info:
   build:
      artifact: ${project.artifactId}
      name: ${project.name}
      description: ${project.description}
      version: ${project.version}
```

when we access the /info end point via mvn  spring-boot:run, we see the following

```
"build": {
    "artifact": "${project.artifactId}",
    "version": "${project.version}",
    "name": "${project.name}",
    "description": "${project.description}"
},
```

The values are not substituted.

Standard Spring Boot Maven POM that has filtering turned on

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Does filtering work for YML files by default?

Comment: What version of Spring Boot? Are you using the spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent pom?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to replicate this, I used the same configuration and it is populating with the value. As mentioned by Dave Syer, I indeed have following value in my parent pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```